# "Could not find method in a parent or ancestor" for camera

Tags: android, camera

I am a newbie in the android World and I am struggling with getting my camera to open on the click of a button in my app. I have followed several tutorials and still not managed to get it to work.

Finally I have come to a stage where I can run the app, and open the camera activity, but when I click the button to take a new picture my app fails.

I have tried various tutorials out now but just can't seem to make it work.

Can anyone tell me from my code below what I need to do to make this work?

I get the following errors:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method dispatchTakePictureIntent(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'button_add_ph'


public class CameraActivity extends Activity {

ImageView result;
static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.camera_activity);

    result = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    Button takePic = (Button)findViewById(button_add_ph);


}

public void dispatchTakePictureIntent(View view) {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        result.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    }
}
```

and my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/notes"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:text="Yo - no notes added for this photo this photo this photo this photo"
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    android:textSize="14dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:maxLength="60"/>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/button_edit"
                    android:text="edit note"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/notes"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:id="@+id/button_add_note"
                    android:text="Add note"/>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:id="@+id/button_delete"
                    android:text="Delete picture"/>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:id="@+id/button_add_ph"
                    android:onClick="dispatchTakePictureIntent"
                    android:text="Take picture" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/backBtn"
                android:onClick="buttonOnClick"
                android:text="Hold dog mund"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

And my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.europcar.mob1exam">

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" android:required="true"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/iconfaetter"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".CameraActivity">

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: What errors do you get? You need to find this information in the Android Monitor window in Android Studio and post it here.

Comment: Hi! thank you

I believe this is the main issue now:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method dispatchTakePictureIntent(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'button_add_ph'

Comment: have you tried just setting an `onClickListener` to your button in your Activity and calling your `dispatchTakePictureIntent` method from it instead?

Comment: So I would do something like this? 

takePic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dispatchTakePictureIntent(View);
            }
        });

What do I need to put in the dispatchTakePictureIntent( ___ ) here ?

Comment: Please edit your question so that you can format code and error messages correctly.